# Why is this contradiction occurs?

Tags: differential-geometry

The following text is from the book pifferential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by M. do Carmo  :

> $\quad $ Let $\alpha:I\to\Bbb R^3$ be a curve parametrized by arc length without singular points of order 1. We shall write the equations of the curve, in a neighborhood of $s_0$, using the trihedron $t(s_0)$, $n(s_0)$, $b(s_0)$ as a basis for $\Bbb R^3$. We may assume, without loss of generality, that $s_0=0$, and we shall consider the (finite) Taylor expansion $$\alpha(s)=\alpha(0)+s\alpha'(0)+\frac{s^2}2a''(0)+\frac{s^3}6\alpha'''(0)+R,$$ where $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to 0}R/s^3=0$. Since $\alpha'(0)=t$, $\alpha''(0)=kn$, and $$\alpha'''(0)=(kn)'=k'n+kn'=k'n-k^2t-k\tau b,$$ we obtain $$\alpha(s)-\alpha(0)=\left(s-\displaystyle\frac{k^2s^3}{3!}\right)t+\left(\displaystyle\frac{s^2k}{2}+\frac{s^3k'}{3!}\right)n-\frac{s^3}{3!}k\tau b+R,$$  where all terms are computed at $s=0$.
>
> $\quad $ Let us now take the system $Oxyz$ in such a way that the origin $O$ agrees with $\alpha(0)$ and that $t=(1,0,0)$, $n=(0,1,0)$, $b=(0,0,1)$. Under these conditions, $\alpha(s)=(x(s),y(s),z(s))$ is given by $$\begin{array}{lll}\displaystyle x(s)& = & \displaystyle s-\frac{k^2s^3}{6}+Rx,             \\         \displaystyle y(s)&=&\displaystyle\frac k2 s^2+\frac{k's^3}{6}+R_y,       \\ \displaystyle z(s)&=&\displaystyle-\frac{k\tau}{6}s^3+R_z,\end{array}\tag{$\textbf{1}$}$$

While the text sounds reasonable on its own but it is consistent with some familiar curve, the helix : $$\alpha (s) = (a \cos (s/c), a \sin (s/c), -b s/c)$$ because for example Taylor series for $\cos (s/c)$ has square of $s$ in its expansion but $x(s)$ in Eq. 1 doesn't have. Why does this contradiction occur?

Answer (score 2):

The passage you've quoted selects an origin and coordinate system, and says that any curve *can* be put into this form.  Your example isn't currently in this form but can be put into it via the proper coordinate change as described in the passage.

Comment: I have two question about your answer: 1- isn't $(1,0,0)=\alpha (0)$ the origin? If so the helix has already have an origin. 2- Do you say that if rotate the given helix such that new bases would be $t=(1,0,0), ...$ so Taylor expansion of its new component will be same as the expansion in the text?

Comment: @Liebe $\alpha(0) = (0,0,0)$ (not (1,0,0)) in the coordinate system in the text.  But yes, once the origin is set properly, I am saying that after rotation, the Taylor expansion (in terms of the arc length $s$) will be the same as that in the text.

Comment: Thanks. Let me work on it...

Comment: I derived $t$ and $n$ and $b$ for the helix $\alpha (s)$. Then tried to find the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $At=(1,0,0)^T$ and $An=(0,1,0)^T$ and $Ab=(0,0,1)^T$ so to multiply $A$ in $\alpha (s)$ and expand it to see if it's same as the text. But because the third component of $n$ of the helix was $0$ so caused one of the $a_{12}$ and $a_{13}$, and one of the $a_{32}$ and $a_{33}$ arbitrary so two of the components of $A$ undetermined. Is there another way to it? Thanks

Comment: You're correct about the third component of $n$, but $t,n,b$ is an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$, so there is a unique orthogonal matrix $A$ that works. Note that the columns of $A^{-1}=A^\top$ are the vectors $t,n,b$ themselves. [Confusing that we now have two Teds involved. :)]